# Vector subscript out of range в цикле for

Tags: c++

Задача вычисления количества предложений. Созданы несколько условий, текст заносится в вектор из файла. 
Предполагаю, что ошибка в том, что, к примеру, на последней итерации при проверке вектора с индексом [i+1] or [i+2] будет выход за пределы размера вектора, но если закомментировать 3-е и последнее условие, ошибка не появляется, хотя предпоследнее условие включает в себя проверку [i+1] элемента. Подскажите, как решить данную проблему и правильно ли я мыслю.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int quant_sent = 0; //количество предложений
    ifstream read;
    read.open("Text.txt");

        vector<char> symbols; //символы из файла


        char n;

        while (read.get(n))
        {
            symbols.push_back(n);
        }
        cout << symbols.size() << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i != symbols.size(); i++) // Точно являются концом предложений
        {
            /*
            if ((int(symbols[i]) == 33) || (int(symbols[i]) == 63)  || (int(symbols[i]) == 46) && (int(symbols[i + 1]) == 46) && \
                (int(symbols[i + 2]) == 46) || (int(symbols[i] == 33) && int(symbols[i + 1] == 63)) || (int(symbols[i]) != 32) && \
                (int(symbols[i + 2] == 46)))
            {
                quant_sent++;
                cout << quant_sent << " : " << i << endl;
            }*/

            if (int(symbols[i]) == '!') { // !
                quant_sent++;
                cout << quant_sent << " : " << i+1 << endl;

            }
            else if (int(symbols[i]) == '?') {// ?
                quant_sent++;
                cout << quant_sent << " : " << i + 1 << endl;
            }
            /*else if (int(symbols[i]) == '.') {// ...
                if (int(symbols[i + 1]) == '.') {
                    if (int(symbols[i + 2]) == '.') {
                        quant_sent++;
                        cout << quant_sent << " : " << i + 1 << endl; // fix
                    }

                }
            }*/
            else if ((int(symbols[i]) == '!') && (int(symbols[i + 1]) == '?')) { // !?
                quant_sent++;
                cout << quant_sent << " : " << i + 1 << endl;
            }
            else if (((int(symbols[i]) != ' ') || (int(symbols[i]) != '.')) && (int(symbols[i + 2]) == '.') && (int(symbols[i+3]) != '.')) {
                quant_sent++;
                cout << quant_sent << " : " << i + 1 << endl;
            }

        }
        read.close();
            cout << "The number of sentences " << quant_sent;
            system("pause");


}
```

Comment: Опишите, что такое предложение, словами. Из исходника это не очень понятно... И уж точно нет смысла хранить все символы в векторе.

Comment: у вас также перемешаны `||` и `&&` так что непонятно что за условие вы там прописывали. пользуйтесь скобками.

Comment: А вообще проблему можно решить добавлением фиктивных пробелов (или что там у вас должно быть по окончании предложения) с проверкой только до размера вектора. Но это, решая проблему с выходом за пределы массива, не решает вопрос неэффективности...

Comment: Может добавить в самое начало этого `if` проверку `i + 3 < symbols.size()`?

Comment: Предложение(условно): J.D. Allen has one dollar! I can find him and meet with him...

Comment: Не надо примеров. Что такое предложение точно? Без точного ТЗ результат будет один - ХЗ. Как только вы дадите определение, станет возможным построение нормального конечного автомата для подсчета количества предложений как наиболее эффективногог решения. Так, как решали вы - уж лучше работать со строками и искать в них подстроки...

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, совершенно не нужный перевод char в int: `int(symbols[i])`.
Во-вторых, у вас в 3 и 4 условиях выход за пределы массива.
В-третьих, 3 условие должно быть первым, т. к. у Вас оно не выполнится никогда. Ну и т. д.
Если Вы хотите перебирать вектор то проще сделать как-то так:

```
    vector<char> symbols; //символы из файла


    char n;

    while (read.get(n))
    {
        symbols.push_back(n);
    }
    cout << symbols.size() << endl;

    bool isLetter = true;
    char localBack;
    while(!symbols.empty())
    {
        localBack = symbols.back();
        if(localBack=='!' || localBack=='?' || localBack=='.')
        {
            if(isLetter)
                quant_sent++;
            isLetter = false;
        }
        else if (localBack!=' ')
            isLetter=true;
        symbols.pop_back();
    }
    read.close();
    cout << "The number of sentences " << quant_sent;
    system("pause");
```

Я, правда, не проверял, но, вроде, должно работать ;)
Без точного ТЗ, как Вам уже написали, задачу не решить. Например:

Кто это сделал? Я. Я это сделал!

Кто это сделал? Я. Я. Иванов это сделал. (Яков Яковлевич Иванов)